# ASP.NET Web Service call failing after changing consuming Site SSL certificate

Tags: asp.net, web-services, ssl, asmx

I'm running into a very weird scenario, have tried a lot of solutions and also tried searching for people having similar issues but couldn't find anything.

I have a webforms ASP.NET application for which the SSL certificate expired a couple of months ago, and we just received the renewed certificate. It was a new certificate instead of a renewal one, but issued to the same URL/SANs. It's also an internal certificate, not externally issued.

After installing the new SSL certificate in our production environment, an internal web service (asmx reference) call that we are making (to a java web service) is failing, complaining about no parameters being sent to the web service. This only happens if I browse through the SSL enabled version of the site, and only in production. The site with SSL works correctly in our dev/stage environments. Prod also works but only if I don't browse through HTTPS.

I cannot paste all the technical exception details, as it's a work related thing, but any help/guidance is appreciated.

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHeaderException: Internal Server Error (Caught exception while handling request: java.lang.Exception: Last Name and/or First Name needs to be provided.)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at OurProgram.com.Company.corp.amssvc.DirWs2.getEmployeeDataByName(String lastName, String firstName, String attData, String strDelim) in D:\somecodehere
```

For additional data, it is also not an IIS website on its own, it's hosted as an application under the Default Website, which is the one that has the SSL binding for the certificat.e

Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR -- Disabled Anonymous Authentication.

Well, after 6 hours of fiddling with and comparing IIS and website configurations, the issue was that for some reason, Anonymous Authentication got enabled somehow after the site had been restarted for the new SSL certificate to kick in. Our application is an intranet one, so the web service takes the credentials of the logged in user. When Anon Auth got enabled somehow, it must have not been passing the correct credentials.

After disabling Anonymous Authentication, the site worked just fine. While it might seem a little related in hindsight, I would've expected a different error, anything other than the web service complaining that no parameters were sent.

Hope this helps someone.